# Extract two numbers from a String with the Java Matcher class

Tags: java, regex

I'ld like to extract two numbers from a string which looks like: "views: 120 upvotes: 540". The expected result is 120 and 540. I'ld like to do this with the Java Matcher class. How can I achieve this, in other words what's the pattern that's required to achieve this?

Comment: `views: (\d+) upvotes: (\d+)`

Comment: When I compile the following code: Pattern.compile("views: (\\d+) upvotes: (\\d+)").matcher("views: 120 upvotes: 540").group(); I still get a IllegalStateException: No match found. exception.

Comment: You need to call `find()` on the `Matcher` before accessing a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `Matcher` you start by compiling a `Pattern`, then you call `matcher(String)` and then you see if it matches. Finally, you can parse the values. Something like,

```
String str = "views: 120 upvotes: 540";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("views:\\s*(\\d+)\\s+upvotes:\\s*(\\d+)",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    int views = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    int upvotes = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    System.out.printf("%d %d%n", views, upvotes);
}
```

Output is

120 540

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the digits, this will work.

```
import java.util.regex.*; 
String matchPattern = "views: (\\d+) upvotes: (\\d+)"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(matchPattern);
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("views: 120 upvotes: 540");
if (match.find()){
   System.out.println(match.group(1));
   System.out.println(match.group(2));
}
```